# cast/convert join type data in codeigniter

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter

how to create query join data when type data is different.when i use CAST code is error.

```
$this->db->join('t_mtr_activity_employee','t_trx_activity.nik = CAST('t_mtr_employee.nik'),'inner');
```

Comment: `...,'t_trx_activity.nik = CAST(\'t_mtr_employee.nik\')',...`

Comment: your code is error $this->db->join('t_mtr_activity_employee','t_trx_activity.nik = CAST(\'t_mtr_employee.nik\')','inner');